# Plot created in knitr via cache=TRUE do not keep the specified margin

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

I am creating plots via knitr by using the `cache=T` chunck option. I am using Rstudio.

The margin not displayed in the output pdf or in the plot saved in the file folder. If I add a box on the outer margin however, it works as expected.

Is there a chunck option to control this ? I looked at the plot options on [https://yihui.name/knitr/options](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/) but did not find any to do the trick.

Here is a Rmd file and the 2 images created, note the use of `par(mar=c(4,4,4,4)` and `theme(plot.margin=unit(rep(2,4),"cm"))`.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,cache=T,dev='jpeg',fig.height=5,fig.width=5)
library(ggplot2)
```

```{r base}
par(mar=c(4,4,4,4))
plot(mtcars$cyl,mtcars$mpg)
```

```{r ggplot}
ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(x=cyl,y=mpg))+
  theme(plot.margin=unit(rep(2,4),"cm"))
```

```{r base_with_box}
par(mar=c(4,4,4,4))
plot(mtcars$cyl,mtcars$mpg)
box("outer", col='blue')  
```
````

[image: image created with ggplot]

[image: image created with base]

[image: image created with base and with a box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF plots are cropped by default in `pdf_document`. See `?rmarkdown::pdf_document`. To disable this feature:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_crop: false
```